# Fortran77 automatically determine how many lines of text are at the top of a data file

Tags: text, fortran77

An (old) instrument of mine is generating ASCII data files with text descriptions at the top of the file, before the data.  But the number of lines of descriptive text varies from run to run.  How can I get Fortran77 to determine this automatically?
Here is an example data file, below the line.

```
Line of explanatory text.

Notice the possible blank lines.
More text.
The number of lines is NOT the same every time.

1.0, 2.0
2.0, 4.0
3.0, 6.0
4.0, 8.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[I found the answer myself. Posting here to help others. It is quite annoying having to wait 8 hours to answer my own question, but I understand why the rule exists. Stupid posers!]

A crude but effective solution, if your text never starts with a number (which is my case):

Assume the input file is named Data.dat.

```
    integer NumTextLines
    real X
    open(8,"Data.dat")
    NumTextLines=-1
50  NumTextLines=NumTextLines+1
    read(8,*,err=50) X
    close(8)
    open(8,"Data.dat")
```

Every time the program tries to read a word from a text line into the real variable X, the read statement errors and program control goes back to line 50. If the read statement is successful, then you don't want to increment NumTextLines any more. Close the file and re-open it to start over from the beginning. But now you know NumTextLines. So you can read the text one line at a time, and either save it or skip it.

{Above method works on most of my files, but not all.  Another way is to read each line into a character*500 variable (say, A), then test the ASCII value of the first element of the character array. But that gets complicated.}